# DateTimeFormatter not using native numerals in Arabic nor Bengali

Tags: java, android, datetime, kotlin, datetime-format

I'm trying to use the `DateTimeFormatter` API to show a specific time in a `TextView` but whenever I run my app whilst my device is set to either the Arabic or Bengali language, the time always seems to show western numerals for some reason. Is this intentional, or is there something that I need to do to fix this?

**Kotlin**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val localizedTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)

        val timeOpen = LocalTime.of(9, 30)
        val timeClose = LocalTime.of(17, 15)

        tv_time.text = (timeOpen.format(localizedTimeFormatter) +
                "\n\n" + timeClose.format(localizedTimeFormatter))
    }
}
```

**Clock app (Arabic)**

[image]

**My app (Arabic)**

[image]

**Clock app (Bengali)**

[image]

**My app (Bengali)**

[image]

Comment: Report that as a bug in the localization data in Java.

Comment: @OleV.V. Where does the _zero digit_ need to code in my code? Any example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as designed. Instances of `DateTimeFormatter`, even the localized ones, use Western/ASCII digits unless explicitly instructed otherwise. The instruction is not hard when you know how:

```
    DateTimeFormatter localizedTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withDecimalStyle(DecimalStyle.ofDefaultLocale());
    
    LocalTime timeOpen = LocalTime.of(9, 30);
    LocalTime timeClose = LocalTime.of(17, 15);
    
    String text = timeOpen.format(localizedTimeFormatter)
            + '\n' + timeClose.format(localizedTimeFormatter);
    System.out.println(text);
```

Output in Bengali locale (bn-BD):

> ```
> ৯:৩০ AM
> ৫:১৫ PM
> ```

And in Arabic (ar):

> ```
> ٩:٣٠ ص
> ٥:١٥ م
> ```

I hope you can translate from my Java code yourself. I believe that it shouldn’t be hard.